# pandas: get scalar value by column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want get a single scalar value from column `store_id` which contains same values for all rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
        "contents": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "store_id": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    }
)

store_id = int(df["store_id"].max())
```

The above is giving me result, just wondering will it be slow if the dataframe is very big. As I am retrieving the dataframe from some other function, say for eg it may returns a dataframe that may contain 10 or 300 or big number of rows(i.e. dynamic) and all will have `store_id` column.

I also tried

```
store_id = df["store_id"].squeeze() # but it did not worked
```

Is there more effecient way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't apply any computation, since all values are the same just get the first one:

```
store_id = df['store_id'].iloc[0]
```

Or:

```
store_id = df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('store_id')]
```

Or:

```
store_id = df.loc[df.first_valid_index(), 'store_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here If you want to retrieve a single scalar value from the "store_id" column and you know that all values in that column are the same, you can use the 'iloc' indexer to get the value at the first index.

Use this.

```
store_id = df["store_id"].iloc[0]
```

Corrected code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
        "contents": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "store_id": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    }
)

store_id = df["store_id"].iloc[0]
print(store_id)
```